# How to call a method using AJAX inside of a form?

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

In this razor view, I have two buttons called previous and next. When the user press these buttons, I need to call a method where stores the user type:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8c8; overflow: auto; width: 100%">
    <h2 class="float-left" style="padding-bottom:5px;">@Model.Quiz.Name</h2>

    <div class="float-right">
        <input name="button" type="submit" value="done" />
    </div>
</div>

@for( ...) {
...
}

<div class="fixednavcontainer">
    <div id="questionnav" class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="questionnavstatus" class="float-left">
            <p>
                Question <span id="currentPage">@ViewBag.CurrentPage</span> of <span id="totalPages">@ViewBag.TotalPages</span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="navbuttons" class="float-right">
            <img id="previous" src="~/Images/previous.png" />
            <img id="next" src="~/Images/next.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="clear-fix" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this should call the buttons

```
private void Save(@model model)
{
    ...
}
```

I would like that ajax does not refresh anything of the page or loads another page, just save and stay the same page. Would it be possible doing this calling a action method since jquery (I guess) ?

Comment: what value would pass to the action method? the whole model?

Comment: @DaveA yes, the whole model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use jQuery and make the call like this:

```
var myModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(MyModel));  //MVC3

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/SomeAction/",
    data: myModel ,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        // Do whatever you have to do...
    }
});
```

And in your controller something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel myModel)
    {
        // Do whatever and return whatever
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be a way to pass the whole model to the method? I mean, instead of `FormCollection`

Comment: Yes you can use jQuery serialize and send the form. It will be picked up as model if input names are same as model variable names.

Answer (score 2):

You can just

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action('yourAddress')",
    data: parametr,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        // Do whatever you have to do...
    }
});
```

and in controller

```
public class XController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult yourAddress(YourModel)
    {
...
    }
}
```